# Creating view in SQL Server with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to crate a view in SQL Server that would take data from this table:

```
pc_name  template powerstate  domain
--------------------------------------
pc1      true     poweredON   domain1
pc2      true     poweredOFF  domain2
pc3      false    poweredON   domain1
pc4      false    poweredOFF  domain2
pc5      true     poweredON   domain1
pc6      true     poweredOFF  domain2
...
```

Select all the computers where column "Template" is "False", separate them by domain and count how many are on/off and the totals, kind of like this:

```
             powerstateON powerstateOFF Total
----------------------------------------------
domain1      100          50            150
domain2       30           5             35
Grand total  130          55            185
```

I have very limited T-SQL knowledge, I know I have to use selects with group by and spent a few hours putting something together but it is not even close, not sure how to do this correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(domain, 'Total'),
       sum(case when powerstate = 'PowerON' then 1 else 0 end) as poweron,
       sum(case when powerstate = 'PowerOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as poweroff,
       count(*) as total
from t
where template = 'false'
group by grouping sets ( (domain), () )
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Interesting how you and @Yogesh Sharma had almost identical answers 30seconds apart, but you were first so I am marking as answer. Thanks again. Will try to understand and learn this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select coalesce(domain, 'Grand Total'),
       sum(case when powerstatus = 'on' then 1 else 0 end) as poweron,
       sum(case when powerstatus = 'off' then 1 else 0 end) as poweroff,
       count(*) as total
from table t
where t.template = 0 -- assuming bit type
group by domain with rollup;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I apprecaite the help!